# How do I replace a component in SolidJS?

Tags: solid-js

I have the following `app.jsx` file. When it runs it appends both `Hello World!` and `Hello Stack Overflow!` to the document body. I need `Hello Stack Overflow!` to replace `Hello World!` (and ideally replacing only the differences), but I can't figure out how to do so.

```
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';

function HelloWorld() {
  return <div>Hello World!</div>;
}

function HelloStackOverflow() {
  return <div>Hello Stack Overflow!</div>;
}

render(() => <HelloWorld />, document.body)
render(() => <HelloStackOverflow />, document.body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single render method but apply conditional rendering inside the root component.

There are several ways:

- Use `Show` component for true/false cases.

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#show
https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/flow_show

- Use ternary operator for true/false cases:

```
<div>{true ? <HelloWorld/ > : <HelloStackOverflow />}</div>
```

You can use conditional expressions inside curly brackets, including function calls like `createMemo`.

- Use `Dynamic` component to insert an arbitrary Component or tag.

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#dynamic

- Use `Switch` when there are more than 2 mutual exclusive conditions.

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#switchmatch

Comment: The actual use case for this is in the context of routing. Clicking on a link will import the component and then render it into the body, replacing the existing component. I'm aware of solid-router but I'm looking to understand the underlying method of replacing components.

Comment: There is nothing magical, jsx can render conditional expressions, so you can use function calls. Usually you will see those function calls are wrapped in createMemo in Solid's core library.

Comment: @Michael You are rendering two apps, is it intentional?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate React's `render(<Component />)` which does replace the existing content.

Comment: @Michael Show also does that. See the example. There is also Switch that can use multiple condinionals.

Comment: There could be hundreds of pages. I need something comparable to `const page = (module) => root.render(module.default())` (if possible) which I can do in React to replace the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252774/discussion-between-snnsnn-and-michael).